# Dll and shared variable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, dll

I have a Dll (C++) who contains a data_seg that is used to share variables among others programs. It works and many program is using it (30+). The problem is that I added this library into a new project, but the variable that I try to access, never change its value. I have to restart the program and now its synchronized with the rest of the other programs and I can see the last value of a variable. Any clue?

Thank you.

Comment: Haaaaaaard to guess without knowing how you actually share that memory...

Comment: DLL variables are not *shared* between users of libraries (users = processes) , each process depending on library has its own variable, probably restarting the program causes you to load the value because it initializes the value from some external informations.

Comment: Not only each user, each process! However, this is only correct if the variable does not point to some kind of shared memory (see e. g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: *I have a Dll (C++) who contains a data_seg that is used to share variables among others programs.* - that's where you went wrong.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040804-00/?p=38253 among others.  You should **never** use a shared data segment.  (But even apart from that, you don't provide enough information to solve the problem.)

Comment: @Aleksander Fular, shared data segments **are** shared among **all** instances of a DLL.

Comment: @Aconcagu, shared data segments are different from anything else in Windows.

Comment: What does "added this library into a new project" mean? Is the new project calling the same DLL? Is the data segment name (Shared) used in one and only one DLL? If you are trying to use the same data segment name in more than one DLL or exe (file) then that won't work.

Comment: Why are we having to guess what your code is?

Answer (score 1):

You dont provide much information - like how you declare your variables or how you modify them. I assume you have written it properly as in MSDN documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

From your description - that variables are synchronized only after application restart, I can only suspect you have some caching problems. I suggest you make your variables volatile and use atomics to modify/read them.

for example:

```
#pragma data_seg("Shared")
volatile LONG g_mydata = 0;
#pragma data_seg()

#pragma comment(linker, "/Section:Shared,RWS")
```

now to modify g_mydata (increment by 1):

```
InterlockedExchangeAdd((PLONG)&g_mydata, 1);
```

Comment: I create a variable like this: int my_variable = 0, and all the variable have its getter/setter, this is how it work. I don't understand why they won't work, because we have over 1000 variable working perfectly like this.