# How to transfer the duplicated handle to the child process?

Tags: c++, winapi

I used DuplicateHandle for sharing a kernel object to the child process, I need to transfer handle of this object to that process, how to do this?

```
int main() {
    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateProcess("sp.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, 
    &cif, &pi);

    HANDLE Semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL);

    DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), Semaphore, pi.hProcess, NULL, 
    DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS, FALSE, 0);

    WaitForSingleObject(Semaphore, INFINITE);
    cout << "Test3: access granted";

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(Semaphore);
}
```

Comment: Write to stdin of the child process; use memory mapped file; use a pragma "shared" variable in  a shared dll between processes; Windows message; Sockets ...

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873

Comment: @VuVirt Nope, none of that is any good, you need to inherit the handle

Comment: Agree. Sorry, didn't read it thoroughly.

Comment: @David, I don't get it.  Why wouldn't DuplicateHandle work?  It isn't as *convenient* as inheritance, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Harry Yes that will work, but VuVirt isn't suggesting inheritance or duplication

Comment: @David, I originally read the question as "how do I tell the child what the value of the newly created duplicate handle is?" and I assume VuVirt did the same.  On the other hand, I see the OPs code doesn't even *know* what the value of the newly created duplicate handle is, so I guess there's some confusion there.

Comment: @VuVirt what do you mean with "pragma shared"? I don't find any information on such in MSDN.

Comment: @tml https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240/How-to-share-a-data-segment-in-a-DLL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795484/dll-and-shared-variable
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc93445e-cec3-456d-9596-15528060dc94/sharing-data-between-processes-using-pragma-dataseg-and-windows-7?forum=vcgeneral
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `DuplicateHandle()` in the parent process, you must specify the child process as the target process, accept the newly duplicated handle, and then use an IPC mechanism of your choosing to send the duplicated handle to the child process, eg:

```
int main() {
    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif, sizeof(cif));
    cif.cb = sizeof(cif);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess("sp.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, 
    &cif, &pi))
    {
        cout << "Test3: CreateProcess failed";
    }
    else
    {
        HANDLE hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL);
        if (!hSemaphore)
        {
            cout << "Test3: CreateSemaphore failed";
        }
        else
        {
            HANDLE hDupSemaphore = NULL;

            if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hSemaphore, pi.hProcess, &hDupSemaphore, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS, FALSE, 0))
            {
                cout << "Test3: DuplicateHandle failed";
            }
            else
            {
                // send hDupSemaphore to child process via IPC ...

                if (WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    cout << "Test3: access granted";
                    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore, 1, NULL);
                }
                else
                    cout << "Test3: WaitForSingleObject failed";

                CloseHandle(hDupSemaphore);
            }

            CloseHandle(hSemaphore);
        }

        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, have the child process be the one to call `DuplicateHandle()` instead. You can pass the parent's process ID and desired handle value to the child process via the command-line or other IPC mechanism, and then have the child process open the process ID with `OpenProcess()` and call `DuplicateHandle()` when it is ready to duplicate the source handle.

Otherwise, you can create the desired handle as inheritable (or use `SetHandleInformation()` to mark it as inheritable after it is created), and then call `CreateProcess()` with the `bInheritHandles` parameter set to TRUE.  Note that this will inherit ALL inheritable handles, unless you [programmatically specify which handles the child process can inherit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873) using [`STARTUPINFOEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686329.aspx) instead of `STARTUPINFO` (Vista and later only).

On the other hand, you are trying to share a Semaphore, which can have a name assigned to it, so you should just create the semaphore with a name assigned and then pass that name to the child process so it can create/open its own semaphore handle using the same name.  This is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438.aspx), and is the preferred way to share kernel objects across process boundaries:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the semaphore object. **If the named semaphore object existed before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`**.

Comment: Ok, so I passed the handle value to the child process and then called `DuplicateHandle(parent_process_handle, handle, GetCurrentProcess(), ...)` But when I try to realese semaphore I get ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE...

Comment: I need to do this exactly with `DuplicateHandle()` I'm not interested in other solutions.

Comment: @Aver why? What are you trying to solve exactly that no other solution can solve? Using `DuplicateHandle()` is not an optimal or preferred solution for sharing semaphores. Assigning a non-NULL name so it can be opened directly by the child process is the best solution.

Comment: I have a task to implement all this solutions, so I have already done  inheritance and named object)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I read Aver's statement as saying the original Semaphore handle, not the duplicate handle, is what was passed to the child process

Comment: @eryksun, Remy, my mistake.